# How to draw a graph with circles and triangles as shown in the image

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Hello, please help me draw this image with latex tikz

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: @JouleV I tried some code that draws the circles but is not working, sorry

Comment: Have a look at [texample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) to get a starting point.

Comment: @asmaberriri Show the code anyway. We don't want to draw it from scratch. Btw they are not circles, they are ellipses.

Comment: Also consider accepting the answer provided @marmot if it satisfies your expectations. It's important for the site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a just-do-it-for-me question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.geometric,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[elli/.style={ellipse,minimum width=4em,minimum
height=2em,draw},trian/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,
draw=brown,minimum width=5em},node distance=2em and
3em,arr/.style={-latex,thick}]
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=1em,row sep=2em,nodes={elli}] (mat)
 { & 8 & \\
  7 & & 11\\
  6 & 10 &9 \\
  };
 \node[above=of mat-1-2,trian,shape border rotate=180] (z0) {$z_0$};
 \node[right=of z0,trian,shape border rotate=180] (z1) {$z_1$};
 \node[below=of z1,elli] (12) {12};
 \node[below=of mat-3-1,trian] (x2) {$x_2$};
 \node[right=of x2,trian] (x0) {$x_0$};
 \node[right=4em of x0,trian] (x1) {$x_1$};
 \draw[arr,dotted] (x2) -- (mat-3-1);
 \draw[arr,dotted] (x2) to[bend left=50] (mat-2-1);
 \draw[arr,dotted] (x2) -- (mat-3-2);
 \draw[arr,dotted] (x0) -- (mat-3-2);
 \draw[arr,dotted] (mat-3-1) -- (mat-2-1);
 \draw[arr,dotted] (mat-2-1) -- (mat-1-2);
 \draw[arr,dotted] (mat-3-2) -- (mat-2-3);
 \draw[arr,dotted] (mat-3-3) -- (mat-2-3);
 \draw[arr,dotted] (mat-2-3) -- (12);
 \draw[arr] (x0) -- (mat-3-1);
 \draw[arr] (x2) -- (mat-3-3);
 \draw[arr] (x1.north) to[out=80,in=-70]  ([xshift=0.3em]mat-2-3.east) 
 to[out=110,in=-20] (mat-1-2);
 \draw[arr] (x1.80) to[bend right=25] (12);
 \draw[arr] (mat-1-2) -- (z0);
 \draw[arr] (12) -- (z1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Whoever down voted this: may I ask why?